# Como pasar información con un input type radio a otro formulario. Ayuda!

Tags: php, entrada

Tengo un formulario que tiene dos opciones: crear clientes o buscar clientes.

Cuando seleccionas la opción de buscar (un icono), se va a otra pagina donde tengo un campo de texto, introduces el nombre y pulsas valida, tras ejecutar el codigo `php` muestra todos los usuarios con ese nombre en una tabla con un input type radio para que puedas coger el deseado (como veis la imagen de abajo ) y llevarlo de nuevo al formulario anterior.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Habitualmente cuando no son datos de un tabla lo suelo hacer con value y pasandolo por metodo post. Pero ahora que la informacion viene de una base de datos no se como puedo hacerlo.

Dejo mi codigo a ver si alguien puede echarme una mano.

```
               $conectar = new mysqli ($host, $user, $pass, $name_bd);
                   if ( $conectar ->connect_error){
                     die("Erorr inesperado: " . $conectar->connect_error);
                            } 
                    //almacenamos la consulta
                    $base = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE idCliente = '$cliente' or Razon_Social like '%$cliente%'";
                    //creamos una array para ir sacando la informacion de la tabla
                    $resultado= $conectar->query($base);
                         while( $row = $resultado->fetch_array()){
                                $Id=$row[0];
                                $Nif=$row[1];
                                $Razon_Social=$row[2];
                                //mostramos la informacion en una tabla  con un Radio
                                echo " <tr>
                                           <td id='ID'><input type='radio' name='identidad' value='$Id' >$Id</td>
                                           <td id='nf'>$Nif</td>
                                           <td id='razon'>$Razon_Social</td>

                                        </tr>"; 
                                    }
                            ?>
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a [es.so].  Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de información como que has probado o que has encontrado por Internet, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas. 

Añadir imágenes a una pregunta es útil cuando el tema hace referencia a la interfaz de usuario o se quieren mostrar gráficos, no para mostrar código fuente

Comment: Si encontraste la solución puedes cerrar tu mismo la pregunta o agrega una solución, revisa como crearla [answer],

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrias hacer es en el formulario poner una condicional al principio para saber si vas a crear un nuevo cliente o editar un como por ejemplo

```
<?php 
  if(isset(POST['idCliente']))
{haces una consulta a la base de datos y traes los datos del cliente
$nif=$fila['nombre de la columna'];
 }

else{
 $nif="";//aca indicas que es un nuevo cliente
 }
```

y abajo pones el formulario y en los input pones

```
value="<?php echo $nif;?>"
```

espero que te sirva

Comment: Hola Emilio y gracias por contestar.

En mi formulario ya tengo un código parecido que me hace justo esa función, verificar si existe el usuario y lo muestra en un input.

Lo que no se, ni tampoco se como enfocarlo en en el apartado "buscador", que es donde me aparecen todos los usuarios que existen (foto de arriba), seleccionar uno con el radio y llevármelo al formulario.

Gracias de nuevo